# highcharts error -13 while the charts has been rendered

Tags: angular, highcharts, ngoninit

I am using highcharts in my angular application. Even though my charts are rendering on load, i am still getting highcharts #error-13 in my console.

I am calling my render chart method inside ngOnInit lifecycle hook.
I also added the check to verify that the method should only be called once the data is available.

My html: 
`<div [attr.id]="chartContainerID" class="chart-container mt-0"></div>`

My ts file:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, {
  chartContainerId: string;

  constructor(private xrangechart: XrangeChartService, ) {
    if (!this.chartContainerId) {
    this.chartContainerId = String(Math.random());
  }}

  ngOnInit() {
    // to do call the service here.
    this.getData();
  }

  renderChart(chartOptions: any) {
    const chart = this.xrangechart.renderChart(this.chartContainerId, chartOptions);
    if (chart) {
       this.plotShapes(chart);
    }
 }
 getData() {
   this.dataservice.subscribe(data => {
    if (data !== null && data !== undefined &) {
      console.log(data);
      this.dataReturned = data;
      this.renderChart(this.setChartOptions());
    }
  });
}


  setChartOptions() {
    const chartOptions: any = {};
    // Setting chart height
    chartOptions.height = 300;
    // Setting the click event on the label
    chartOptions.data = this.dataReturned.data;
    // to set the yaxis
    chartOptions.yAxis = {
        gridLineWidth: chartContainer.gridLineWidth,
        margin: 0,
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        categories: this.data.categories,
        reversed: true
      };
    return chartOptions;
  }


  plotShapes(chart: any) {
    // some logic to plot shape
}

}
```

expected: The error in the console should not be present and the charts should be rendered without any error

Comment: if you can reproduce this on stackblitz, it'll be easier to see what may be the issue

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up due container not found where your chart will be draw. like:

```
<div [attr.id]="chartContainerID" class="chart-container mt-0"></div>
```

make sure your div have id attribute before chart's rendering. you have to call chart render method after you `div` have an `id` attribute. because as seed your code you have dynamic `id` in your `div`.

Comment: I tried added a check before i call the method to render the chart to check if the container id is present. But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does your container div is visible in DOM?

Comment: yes.. the charts are rendered too.. but in the console the error appears.

Comment: Can you please share your source code to find the issue?

Comment: @Thushara, can you please share solution or comment, I am facing same issue. Thanks.